# Scheduling algorithms with weighted tasks

Tags: scheduling

I am working on a problem where you have tasks: $t_1, t_2, t_3,...$ with different weights $w_1, w_2, w_3,...$. The objective is to maximize the combined weight of the tasks that are finished before their deadline. Are there any scheduling algorithms for this problem?

Comment: Did you do a basic search of the scheduling literature?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri A very cursory one. Did not see anything immediately, but that could just be an oversight on my part.

Comment: You can look at Pinedo's book. https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319265780. Check  the notion of tardiness as well.